# What color would a purple alien blush?

Tags: aliens

I know that we blush because of something to do with our blood, so what color would someone with purple skin blush? Darker purple?

Comment: Without much more detail this question is unanswerable. Could you tell us about them, their blood composition, what flushing does to them?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We don't know what blood these creatures have, or what its colours are.  Until that is added to the question, there's no answer to this.

Comment: You really might want to consider putting this question in the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) on Meta. It will really help you with your question writing skills.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the color of the alien's blood. If they bleed green, then green; likewise, if they have iron-based blood like we do that's red, then they would blush like we would.

Comment: A purple skin would more or less block it, depending on how much pigment there is.

Comment: Also fair, and in fact true, but in the event that the alien *can* blush, it would be dependent on blood color.

Comment: The colors might interact.

Comment: Then simply mix colors. Adding more depth to the analysis of how the colors will interact requires more detail (which as the banner at the top of this page states this question lacks) such as how deep the skin is and how deep the pigment penetrates into that skin, plus how much blood is near the surface at the time of blushing, etc. etc. etc..